# Concatenate a filename to a directory name

Tags: c, file, strcat

I want to add a directory to a filename in c but i get an error like:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here is my code:

```
char fname[255];
char directoryTmp[262];

/*Working Code for entering the filename fname with fgets() */
...

/* specify the directory */ 
directoryTmp[0] = "/";
directoryTmp[1] = "f";
directoryTmp[2] = "i";
directoryTmp[3] = "l";
directoryTmp[4] = "e";
directoryTmp[5] = "s";
directoryTmp[6] = "/";

/* Copy fname at the end of directoryTmp */
strcat(directoryTmp,fname);

/* new fname with the directory, should look like: "/files/afilename */
for(i=0;i<strlen(directoryTmp);i++){
    fname[i] = directoryTmp[i];
}
```

//edit

OK this is my new code, but I still get the same error code:

```
char fname[255];
char directory[262];

directory[sizeof(directory) - 1] = '\0';
strncpy(directory,sizeof(directory) - 1, "/files/");


for(i=0;i<strlen(directory);i++){
    fname[i] = directory[i];
}
puts(fname);

fname[sizeof(fname) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: Beside the problem mentioned by Alexander in his answer, you're missing the trailing null character after initializing `directoryTmp`.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler yell out warnings feeding it those sources.

Comment: You can initialize `directoryTmp` directly, like `char directoryTmp[256] = "/files";`. Also, your `for` loop calls `strlen` again and again for no good reason.

Comment: NULL has to be after "/files/" not in the end of directory (which is sizeof(directory) -1, because then you have "/files/<total garbage till 261th index>\0"

Comment: Thanks zoska, the hint that the NULL had to be after /files/ and not at the end of directory fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you forgot to NUL terminate your string when filling `directoryTmp` (in C strings are array of `char` that by convention ends at the first `char` whose value is `0`). Then, when `strcat` try to append `fname` it begins by iterating over `directoryTmp` looking for a NUL character. As the array is initialized on the stack (at least I guess from the code snippet), its content is undefined, and `strcat` scan past the end of the array which is undefined behavior (in your particular case this cause a segmentation fault).

So, the correct code would be:

```
/* specify the directory */ 
directoryTmp[0] = '/';
directoryTmp[1] = 'f';
directoryTmp[2] = 'i';
directoryTmp[3] = 'l';
directoryTmp[4] = 'e';
directoryTmp[5] = 's';
directoryTmp[6] = '/';
directoryTmp[7] = 0;   // NUL terminate the string
```

Or as mentioned by others, just use `strncpy`:

```
memset(directoryTmp, 0, sizeof(directoryTmp));
strncpy(directoryTmp, "/files/", sizeof(directoryTmp) - 1);
```

Note that `strncpy` [does not guarantee](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) that the string will be NUL terminated, so we have to take care of that ourselves.

Comment: but you didn't take care of that. you've set directoryTmp[261] to NULL, but still after "/files/" there's garbage.

Comment: According to the documentation of `strncpy`, it pads `dest` with NUL characters if length of `source` is less than `n`: Copies the first num characters of source to destination. If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it.

Answer (score 2):

`char`s are put in single quotation marks (`''`), not double (`""`). You're assigning string literals to each array index.

Comment: "*You're assigning string literals to each array index.*" At least the OP tries to do this., which however will not work except on an 8bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this

```
char fname[255];
char directoryTmp[262];

/*Working Code for entering the filename fname with fgets() */
...

/* specify the directory */ 
strcpy(directoryTmp,"/files/");


/* Copy fname at the end of directoryTmp */
strcat(directoryTmp,fname);

/* new fname with the directory, should look like: "/files/afilename */
for(i=0;i<strlen(directoryTmp);i++){
    fname[i] = directoryTmp[i]; //You need to take care here. Because size of the fname is 255 and size of the directoryTmp is 262. you should check length of the fname in for loop.  
}
```